# Refering to an entity from within its class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, core-data

I always have my core data entities to use NSManagedObject subclasses.

Inside these classes I always have methods like this

```
+ (Entity *)newItemWithName:(NSString *)name InManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

// bla bla bla
```

and inside these methods you will eventually find something like

```
anItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
anItem.name = name;
```

My problem is this @"Entity".

Is there a way to refer to the entity's name from within these methods without having to type the entity name every time and minimize the chance of a typo/bug? or in other words, there is something else that could be put there to discover the name of the entity by itself?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `NSStringFromClass([self class])`.

However, this is also fragile as you might change the implementing class name in IB.

Comment: what do you mean by fragile? If the name changes in IB wouldn't the string returned changed too? Under which circumstances would this fail?

Comment: If you look at IB, you would see that it is possible to define a name for the entity and a class name for the entity. since they can vary from each other: <EntityName> != `NSStringFromClass([self class])` and the insertion will fail.

Comment: AH, I see, but in my case I always follow the same name for both but I will keep an eye on it. At least this will easy 99% of things. Thanks.